# Meteor build apk not running in mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, meteor, meteor-react

I am trying to install an application made in meteor in my Android mobile. The application is build through

`meteor build /home/sampad/meteor_apk --server 192.168.1.27:3000`

This app consist of 2 templates. When I click on submit it takes me to the next template when run in desktop through `meteor`. But when running it in mobile the submit button click does not take me anywhere, also I cannot see any error.

Attaching the code:

```
<!-- main.html -->
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Accounts Page</a>
                </div>
    </div>
</nav>
            <div class="container">
            {{#if currentUser}}
            {{>dashboard}}
            {{else}}
                 {{> register}}

                 {{> login}}
            {{/if}}

            <hr>

            </div>
```

```
<template name="register">
    <form>

        <h3>Registration Page</h3>
        E-mail :   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type ="text" id="email"><br>
        Password : <input type="password" id="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save details"> &nbsp; <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</template>

<template name="login">
    <form>
        <h3>Log In Page</h3>
        E-mail :   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type ="text" id="login-email"><br>
        Password : <input type="password" id="login-password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"> &nbsp; <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</template>

<template name="dashboard">
     <p> You 're logged in </p>
     <p><a href ="#" class="logout" >Log Out</a></p>
</template>

<!-- main.js -->
    if(Meteor.isClient)
{
    Template.register.events({
        'submit form':function(event,template){
        event.preventDefault();
        var emailVar = template.find('#email').value;
        var passwordVar = template.find('#password').value;
        //template.find('#message').append("Clicked submit");
        console.log('Form submitted');
        Accounts.createUser({
            email:emailVar,
            password:passwordVar        
        });
        }
    });

    Template.login.events({
        'submit form':function(event,template){
        event.preventDefault();
        var emailVar = template.find('#login-email').value;
        var passwordVar = template.find('#login-password').value;
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar,passwordVar);
        }
    });

    Template.dashboard.events({
    'click.logout':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.logout();
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with explicitly specifying the protocol to reach your server?

`--server http://192.168.1.27:3000`